# How do I get a <div> element to fall just under another <div> element

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get the image in DIV scroll-marker to fall behind my fixed header DIV, I have tried using z-index: -4000!important; in other words reverse it totally against the header this does not seem to work(I have also tried the z-index altogether still did not work). I would really appreciated some help with this, I think my approach my be incorrect.

```
CSS below for the two divs.

 /* Header Div */
 .fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4000;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;   
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #999;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #999;

}
/* Element to go behind the fixed header */
.scroll-marker img { 
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                clear: both;
                z-index: -4000!important;
                position: relative;
}


CSS for logo div.

#logo {
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}
#logo p {
    font-size:11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1!important;
}
#logo p a {
     color: #868686;
 }
 #logo p a:hover {
     color: #A4C940;
 }
 #logo img {
     margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo_info {
    margin: 10px;
 }
 #logo_info p {
    font-size:11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1!important;
}
#logo_info p a {
    color: #868686;
 }
#logo_info p a:hover {
    color: #A4C940;
}

HTML for the header Region

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body> 
<!-- preloader-->
<div class="whitebg">
<div id="spinner"></div>
</div>
<header class="fixed-header">

<div class="centered-wrapper">

<div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/value_images/VPM_global3.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="scroll-marker"><img src="images/value_images/scroll-marker.png"></div>

</div><!-- End Centered Wrapper -->

</header>
<section>
Another Section..............
</section>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: could you possibly provide a jsfiddle, as currently, it's hard to visualize what you're trying to acheive?

Comment: Just tested that and seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/asm0kejr/

Comment: the jsfiddle emmanuel provided shows exactly what is needed he used my css and it works, I am stumped why it does not work in my document.

Comment: Provide your HTML as well. I have a feeling you are dealing with a positioning hang up with the positioning of your elements on the page.

Comment: I have added the HTML for the Header region as I cannot figure this issue out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to place an element behind something it is inside (it is very much like trying to place a plate simultaneously inside and under a box). You would have to move the image element outside the header element.